# Bug in design when using Internet Explorer 8

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, internet-explorer-8

In Internet Explorer 8, the image of Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow is not clear in the profile page:

[image]

The image of the badge and bold text in the answer has more than three downvotes and is not properly displayed:

[image]

In more answers than 3dv's answer, the bold test does not look proper.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IE8 isn't supported any longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (we support the latest 2 versions of an major browser).

Our goal for old browsers is that the site renders and is usable, but does not need to look perfect.  Dropping IE8 support allows us to clean up a whole sloth of IE-specific hacks in layout and CSS rules (ever wonder why everything's floated? yeah no `inline-block` in older IE versions).

We want IE8 to be usable, but minor rendering bugs (especially in minority cases like this) will no longer be fixed.

Comment: thankyou...looks like now i should also .. not consider id .. while doing css stuff